# Python: Setting tuples from csv file

Tags: python, csv

So essentially what I have is a csv file which is loaded in via some function, lets call it

```
get_csv
```

So when I have this data, I want to create a new function to format the data sent from the server into tuples. Which I will call

```
csv_format
```

So assuming the csv comes with 9 columns, how would I set it up so the first column is an int, the next two are floats and the last ones are strings?  I know this sounds difficult but I hope you can help me out here.

```
def csv_format(data):
...
....
return get_csv(data)
```

So essentially I just need to format the tuples so that it outputs like this:

```
(first, second, third, (fourth, fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, ninth))
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Setting up tuples with a large csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582559/python-setting-up-tuples-with-a-large-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
import csv

def get_csv(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return list(csv.reader(f))

def csv_format(data):
    return [(row[0], row[1], row[2], tuple(row[3:])) for row in data]
```

### Example

*Input*

```
first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth
```

*Output*

```
[('first', 'second', 'third', ('fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth'))]
```